# Firefox ignores cache.manifest

Tags: html, firefox, browser-cache

I'm trying to add offline caching to my HTML5 apps.  I've amended the HTML file to have

```
<html lang="en" manifest="cache.manifest">
```

I added the cache.manifest file that looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#VersionHash: fd30cdac1dd02ec2077dd5ca1b097369
#VersionTime: October 28 2014 10:59:48

CACHE:
css/ebot.css
js/ebot.js
js/jquery.min.js
js/actionlog.js
images/arrow-right.js
... and so on - about 50 files total ...

NETWORK:
getdata.php
emaillog.php
uploadlog.php
```

and now I'm testing it.  This works perfectly fine in Chrome, however Firefox seems to simply ignore the manifest parameter.  When I look at the "network" tab in the dev tools, file `cache.manifest` is not being loaded at all.

I am using [Jonathan Stark's script](https://jonathanstark.com/blog/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache?filename=2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/) for debugging - and I can see the cache being populated in Chrome - with the eventual "loaded".

Yet, in Firefox, all I see in the console is

```
"online: yes, event: checking, status: uncached" cache.js:30
"online: yes, event: error, status: uncached (prolly a syntax error in manifest)" cache.js:30
```

repeated over and over, every second.  From what I can see, Firefox is ignoring the `manifest` attribute on `html` and hence the cache is not updated.

How can I get Firefox to honour the `manifest`?

For the reference, I'm testing on Firefox 32.0.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: i'm guessing you've read a lot of stuff like [this?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest)

Comment: @MrCoder That link concerns itself with packaging HTML5 apps to appload to mozilla store.  I'm talking about a generic HTML5 app to be served via browser from my website.